# A template struct as a function argument

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, struct, tree

I have my struct Dictionary

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct Diccionary {
    friend void insert<T, U>(Diccionario<T,U>& d, const T& c, const U& v);
    friend void insertAux<T, U>(typename Diccionary<T,U>::Nodo* a, const T& c, const U& v);    

private:
    struct Nodo{
        T t;
        U u;
        Nodo* left;
        Nodo* right;
    };

    Nodo* root;
    Nodo* iterator;
    int size;    
};
```

I have an error with the arguments of insertAux, I dont know how to give to this function a pointer to a Node. The problem is that the Node is in a struct, so the compiler tells me:

> error: no type named ‘Nodo’ in ‘struct Diccionario

I need to give to this function a Node because then I will use a recursive algorithm, and I cant give to the function a Dictionary type, because the tree and the dictionary are different.

Comment: Put type definition before friends declaration.

Comment: What is the definition of `Diccionario`?

Comment: But the problem is that te type must be private, also de insertAux function is private but I have tu put it there. So if the type still being private, what I can do? The type is private, but the function (is private) must be friend

Comment: You can have multiple `private` sections in your class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you, what is wrong. At the place, where you use it, `Diccionary<T,U>::Nodo` is not yet defined.

Solution 1: define it before.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct Diccionary {
private:
    struct Nodo{
        T t;
        U u;
        Nodo* left;
        Nodo* right;
    };

public:
    friend void insert<T, U>(Diccionario<T,U>& d, const T& c, const U& v);
    friend void insertAux<T, U>(typename Diccionary<T,U>::Nodo* a, const T& c, const U& v);    

private:
    Nodo* root;
    Nodo* iterator;
    int size;    
};
```

Solution 2: since you use it as a pointer, it is enough to declare it before.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct Diccionary {
private:
    struct Nodo;
public:
    friend void insert<T, U>(Diccionario<T,U>& d, const T& c, const U& v);
    friend void insertAux<T, U>(typename Diccionary<T,U>::Nodo* a, const T& c, const U& v);    

private:
    struct Nodo{
        T t;
        U u;
        Nodo* left;
        Nodo* right;
    };

    Nodo* root;
    Nodo* iterator;
    int size;    
};
```

As a general note: use `friend` as rarely as possible. I have not yet written a single C++ program, that needed `friend` anywhere in my code, and I have written quite some. I consider it a code smell.

Also this looks like you are trying to implement your own kind of tree structure. Please consider to use standard library containers. You probably won't get it better and if you did, you'd ask different questions.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I think it solves my problem. I am not trying to improve the standard library containers, but this is class work, so I need to do it as my teacher want. Thank you very much!